# How to load balance sockets using ingress nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, socket.io, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

In kubernetes I have a deployment of 3 pods in charge of the sockets.

I wish to load balance the traffic between the pods of the deployment. To do it, I'm using the NGINX Ingress controller installed via Helm using the chart [stable/nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress).

The problem is that the clients always connect to the same pod. There is no balancing.

To test the load balancing, I'm using sevaral phones using the data (2-6 phones). Each of them opening a socket connection.

I have 2 ingress rules. For the sockets I'm using:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-socket-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "node-socket-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"    
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$host"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.com
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:     
          - path: /socket.io/
            backend:
              servicePort: 4000
              serviceName: node-socket-service
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-socket-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: node-socket
  ports:
    - port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

I tried to change the value of `upstream-hash-by` with : `$binary_remote_addr` `$remote_addr` `$host` `ewma` `$request_uri`, unsuccessful...

I'm wondering if the way that I'm doing my test is good. May be the load balancing is working well but it needs to have more clients.

Comment: Hi, what cluster infrastructure/platform do you use? Also what Kubernetes version and which network plugin/ CNI do you have installed?

Comment: Hi, I'm using K8s v1.14.5 on DigitalOcean. I've never installed any network plugin/CNI, I supposed that I have the default ones ( I'm a beginner and I don't realy know this part of K8s).

Comment: Any news ? Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: I guess $request_uri is the same for all connections. Could it be that $host, remote_addr etc also are the same because of a reverseproxy in front of your Ingress? I'm using kubernetes in a private hosted data center and the requester-IP is always the same (a scaler/balancer in front of the cluster/ingress). To reach your requirement, couldn't you just remove upstream-hash-by completly? It should just distribute it randomly to all of the pods.

Comment: "...and the requester-IP is always the same" it could be an explanation ( I'm using DigitalOcean with a loadBalancer ). Because I'm using sockets I need to use upstream-hash-by to enable sticky session based on IP.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the following architecture to reach your pod:

Ingress controller --->  kubernetes service ---> kubernetes deployment (POD)

If this is the case, then you are using load balancing with a statistical round robin policy already. For which I would conclude that your deployment only has one replica. Check the amount of replicas by running `kubectl describe deployment $YOUR_DEPLOYMENT`. Increase the amount of replicas by running `kubectl scale deployment --replicas=5`.

In case you are using a different architecture I would need to check it in order to verify why load balancing is not working. Most likely you are not using a Deployment bud a Pod to deploy your container.

Comment: Yes I'm using the architecture that you described, I already have 3 replicas :
Replicas: 3 desired | 3 updated | 3 total | 3 available | 0 unavailable

Comment: Ok, then how do you know only one pod is being used? As I mentioned a plain kubernetes service uses a statistical round robin policy by default.

Comment: I'm using :  kubectl log -f $POD_NAME on every replica. Every time that I have a new socket connection I print the socket's id. The prints occur in only one pod.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: $arg_token` instead of `$host`